# Hexlify input using Binascii

Tags: python, python-3.x, binascii

I am trying to `hexlify` input from user but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

If I use `b` before string then it works but how can I do it with input?
Here is the code:

```
import binascii as bs
text = input('Please Enter Your text:')
bs.hexlify(text)
```

I tried doing:

```
text = input('Please enter you text:')
import binascii as bs
bs.hexlify(bytes(text))
```

But it gives the following error:

```
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you Google "How to convert str to bytes in Python" or checked `bytes`'s docs?

Comment: `hexlify` simply expects bytes, how it is passed to it is not its problem. The second error is from `bytes()` call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add encoding parameter to `bytes`:

```
import binascii as bs
text = input('Please Enter Your text:')
bs.hexlify(bytes(text, encoding="utf8"))
```